# How to create floating search bar on a web page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jakarta-ee, css

I am trying to create a floating ticker for my customer websites which will display their activity details, and am planning to expose this as an embedded code for them to use.

I have three questions:

1. What is this technically called so that I can do more research on this
2. What is the best practice to create a floating table or div section: Ex:[springSource.org](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html): has a search bar which floats on their webpage and has some animation
3. How can I uniquely identify each website request from my embed code so that I pass the relevant information back

Thanks in advance for your time and help. Will appreciate any questions/comments.

Technologies used: Spring, JSP (Am open to use other UI technologies like jQuery, CSS3, HTML5 etc.,)

Comment: Best practice would be to create a DIV with `position:fixed` in the CSS styles. No scripting required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the fixed search bar at the bottom of the page, you can use for example:

```
#search_bar {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
}
```

If you want your users to be able to embbed some kind of widget on their site, they'll have to embbed an iframe:

```
<iframe src="//www.yourwebsite.com/some_page?params=...></iframe
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Is it possible to use my css formatting on customer website for this iframe? I know I can use css for contents with-in iframe, but how can I apply my CSS to iframe element ?Thanks.